# How can i make smaller js code in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 css classes with different type of colors in a buttons for on hover function, in my page might be have 5 buttons with diffenent classes. When i hover the each button, color should be set as per respective class name so far its working fine for me. but now i can see huge code, i want to make it smaller. Please suggest anyone.

```
$('[class^="button"]').parent().each(function(){
    var parentElement = $(this);
    var buttonfullwidth = $(parentElement).hasClass('buttonfullwidth');
    var buttonfullwidth_1 = $(parentElement).hasClass('buttonfullwidth_1');
    var buttonfullwidth_2 = $(parentElement).hasClass('buttonfullwidth_2');
    var buttonfullwidth_3 = $(parentElement).hasClass('buttonfullwidth_3');
    var buttonfullwidth_4 = $(parentElement).hasClass('buttonfullwidth_4');

    if(buttonfullwidth_1 !== false) {
        $(parentElement).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('buttonfullwidth_1');

        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('buttonfullwidth_1');

        });
    }
    if(buttonfullwidth_2 !== false) {
        $(parentElement).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('buttonfullwidth_2');

        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('buttonfullwidth_2');

        });
    }
    if(buttonfullwidth_3 !== false) {
        $(parentElement).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('buttonfullwidth_3');

        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('buttonfullwidth_3');

        });
    }
    if(buttonfullwidth_4 !== false) {
        $(parentElement).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('buttonfullwidth_4');

        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('buttonfullwidth_4');

        });
    }
    if(buttonfullwidth !== false) {
        $(parentElement).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('buttonfullwidth');

        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('buttonfullwidth');

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use js for that, that's something you should do in css.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need JavaScript to do hovering styles. Just do this in the CSS: `.buttonfullwidth:hover { ...hover styles here... }`

Comment: Yeah, I agree it is possible in css but in my case is different scenarios so that i came with javascript.

Comment: Because, button has toggle functionality and two type of hovering color and background colors i'm using

Comment: You could use a `for` loop, which iterates through your `if` statements.

Comment: Most likely this can be done with just html and css anyway. If you give use [mcve] with html and css also, someone kind enough could show you how.

Comment: Please show a minimal html structure for those buttons, that will work with the given code.

Answer (score 1):

You need CSS for this job by using the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo selector

> The `:hover` CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) matches when the user interacts with an element with a pointing device, it is generally triggered when the user hovers over an element with the mouse pointer.

For example, if you want this button to turn blue when hovered:

```css
.myButton {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">Hover this button</button>
```

Notice how I can set properties to the element when it is in his hover state.

So for your code you simply need to use the following selectors:

```
buttonfullwidth
buttonfullwidth:hover

buttonfullwidth_1
buttonfullwidth_1:hover

buttonfullwidth_2
buttonfullwidth_2:hover

buttonfullwidth_3
buttonfullwidth_3:hover

buttonfullwidth_4
buttonfullwidth_4:hover
```

in the same manner as I did in my example.